# Different hover effects [html/css]

Tags: html, css, hover

I have a menu with a hover effect on all listed links/ items. I want to put a Home icon (the house), whose hover effect to be switching between 2 identical images with different color, OK I got this, but the main hover effect still applies to it as background.

For example, when I move the mouse over any of the links the hover effect is orange background around the text, and I want to remove that effect from the Home icon only( there's already switching between white house and orange house on mouse over).

I've tried so many things and still nothing successful...

Thank you in advance!

[Picture of what I'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysjiU.png)

HTML code:

```
<div class="Menu">

<div class="ner">
<ul>

        <li class="home">
             <a  href="#" ><img onmouseout="this.src='home1.png'" onmouseover="this.src='home2.png'" src="home1.png" width=25px; height=25px;></a></li>


            <li><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
            <li class="drop">
                <a href="#">Item2</a>

                <div class="dropdownContain">
                    <div class="dropOut">
                        <div class="triangle"></div>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Blog 1</li>
                            <li>Blog 2</li>
                            <li>Blog 3</li>
                            <li>Blog Blog 4</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Item3</a></li>


<li class="drop">
                <a href="#">Item4</a>

                <div class="dropdownContain">
                    <div class="dropOut">
                        <div class="triangle"></div>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Blog 1</li>
                            <li>Blog 2</li>
                            <li>Blog Blog 3</li>
                            <li>Blog Blog 4</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </li>
<li><a href="#">Item5</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item6</a></li>


</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
.Menu {
    background: #44474B;
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    width:900px;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 55px;
    min-width: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
}

.Menu ul{ float:left;}

.Menu li{position:relative; z-index:10; float:left; list-style:none; margin:0 15px; }

.Menu a{ padding:11px 18px; color:#373737; list-style:none; color:#FFF; text-decoration:none; 
        -webkit-transition: all .3s linear 0s;
    -moz-transition: all .3s linear 0s;
    -ms-transition: all .3s linear 0s;
    -o-transition: all .3s linear 0s;
    transition: all .3s linear 0s;}

.Menu ul li a:hover{ border-radius:6px;
background: #ffa84c; /* Old browsers */
/* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ffa84c 0%, #ff7b0d 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffa84c), color-stop(100%,#ff7b0d)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ffa84c 0%,#ff7b0d 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #ffa84c 0%,#ff7b0d 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #ffa84c 0%,#ff7b0d 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #ffa84c 0%,#ff7b0d 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffa84c', endColorstr='#ff7b0d',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */

}

.Menu .home a:hover {
background-color: green; !important
text-decoration:none; !important
}

.ner{width:900px; margin:0 auto; padding-top:0; padding-left:0;}
```

The green background color is for testing purposes only.

Comment: you need to post your code in the question to get help

Comment: I don't know how to post it here, so I did it in Google Docs... Im sorry about that.

Comment: you just put it in your question, indented four spaces.  see http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: 1. Please do not put "SOLVED" in question title. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116101/204869) for details. 2. Please do not post an answer in the question. If you have an answer. post it in the answer section. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a class to the anchor tag of the home icon and implement the different css changes to that class like this:

HTML:

```
<li>
    <a class="home" href="#" ><img onmouseout="this.src='home1.png'" onmouseover="this.src='home2.png'" src="home1.png" width="25" height="25">
    </a>
</li>
```

CSS:

```
a:hover.home {
  background-color: green; !important
  text-decoration:none; !important
}
```

Here's a jsfiddle example with above codes: http://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/g2vqL0ms

And `width=25px; height=25px;` should be `width="25" height="25"`

Comment: Give me a sec. I will post a jsfiddle with above codes

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle example with above codes: https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/g2vqL0ms/

Add the class="home" to your anchor tag and not your `li` tag btw

Comment: And `width=25px; height=25px;` should be `width="25" height="25"` btw

Comment: I did exactly what you wrote and nothing happened... Btw see the picture in the main post . Thanks for trying to help me :}